# Assembly.CodeBase: when is it no file-URI?

Tags: .net, assemblies, environment

Assembly.Location gives a plain path to the assembly. Unfortunately this is empty when running in a shadowed environment, such as unit test or ASP.NET. Hovever, the Codebase property is available and provides a URI that can be used instead. In which cases it returns no URI starting with `file:///`? Or in other words: what are the cases in which this won't work or will return unusable results?

```
Assembly assembly = GetType().Assembly;    
Uri codeBaseUri = new Uri(assembly.CodeBase);
string path = codeBaseUri.LocalPath;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to load assemblies directly over HTTP, such as in a ClickOnce deployment:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("http://server/app.dll");
Uri codeBaseUri = new Uri(assembly.CodeBase);
Debug.Assert(codeBaseUri.Scheme == "http"); 
Debug.Assert(codeBaseUri.LocalPath == "");
Debug.Assert(assembly.Location == "");
```

Comment: Never used this directly, although I used ClickOnce before. You're probably right, but what if my code would be inside your app.dll and the app.dll was downloaded the way you described. What am I getting in path? %LOCALAPPDATA%\Apps\2.0\something? Or would it fail completely?

Comment: path (i.e. Uri.LocalPath) is empty unless the URI contains a file:// link. Likewise, assembly.Location is also blank. I thought I had another property for finding the shadow-copied location (which is guaranteed to be a real file), but I can't see it just now.

Answer (score 0):

Also, # char is threated as a fragment separator. 
See http://blogs.msdn.com/ncl/archive/2010/02/23/system-uri-f-a-q.aspx (section 9) for short explanation.

Use Assembly.EscapedCodeBase instead of Assembly.CodeBase to fight it.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question, but I found a relevant, consderably new feature changing the picture: packing a dotnet core app into a single file will break `Assembly.CodeBase` according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#api-incompatibility